# ResetPassword within my flutter app using FirebaseAuth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to reset the password of user account inside my flutter app rather then resetting the password through the link that is sent to the email,
i have found a method in FirebaseAuth is :

`confirmResconfirmPasswordReset(code, newPassword)`
i can use it after using of :
`sendPasswordResetEmail`
but as i said the problem here is the email that i have receive to reset the password contain a link with oodCode for reseting the password on a website,

i just want to display only the oodCode in that email to use it with the `confirmResconfirmPasswordReset` function of FirebaseAuth.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented this into one of my apps. Check out this github gist with my code: https://gist.github.com/HadyMash/c3a2180f72efa8e0cae8e01f2d0105c2.

I have some custom widgets in there so you can replace widgets such as `ThemedButton()` with any of Flutter's buttons or anything which would achieve the same purpose. If there are any widgets which are unclear with what you should replace them with let me know and I'll tell you what they are or provide code for them.

Also I posted my entire auth.dart file but only a few functions are needed so you can check which those are and implement them into your auth system.

Result looks something like this: https://dsc.cloud/d061d0/Simulator-Screen-Recording-iPhone-12-Pro-Max-2021-06-14-at-22.41.23

Comment: thank you for your respond, but my question is about reset password through email of un logged user, not for changing the password of already logged user